# Expresso store delete one item per time

Tags: expresso-store, shopping-cart

I have a cart with a delete button in it. It works fine when I have 1 item in my cart, but when I have an item in my cart with a quantity of more then one, it deletes all the quantities of that item. So when I have an item in my cart 2 times and I delete it, it deletes all 2 of them.

This is my delete button:

```
<input type="submit" name="remove_items[{key}]" class="remove" value="&#xf00d;" />
```

It has `{items}` tags above and under it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default functionality of the remove items tag, it's an all or nothing kind of tag. You should look at adding a quantity drop down or input field and use the Update Cart button if you are wanting to change quantities of items in your cart.